# Magento 2 layout file marketplace_seller_account_create.xml isn't loading

Tags: magento2, layout

I've a controller file   Amitshree\Marketplace\Controller\Seller\Account\Create.php with following code:

```
<?php
    namespace Amitshree\Marketplace\Controller\Seller\Account;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

    class Create extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        /**
         * @var $resultPageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        /**
         * Create seller account constructor.
         * @param Context $context
         * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        )
        {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        }

        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            //exit('hi'); // works fine
            $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        }
    }
```

and layout file **marketplace_seller_account_create.xml** with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Request your account as a Seller.</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="seller.account.create" label="Create Seller Account" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="seller-account-create">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="seller_account_create" template="seller/account/create.phtml"></block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="marketplace" frontName="marketplace">
            <module name="Amitshree_Marketplace"></module>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

When I visit the url [website.com/marketplace/seller/account_create/](http://website.com/marketplace/seller/account_create/) , it shows a blank page without any errors. Naming convention of my layout file is wrong?

Comment: Show your routes.xml

Comment: @SohelRana: Added in question. my template file is present at `templates/seller/account/create.phtml`. I've other layout file `marketplace_seller_login.xml`  which works fine while accessing http://website.com/marketplace/seller/login/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller execute method

```
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //exit('hi'); // works fine
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Your layout content should be [ marketplace_seller_account_create.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Request your account as a Seller.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="seller_account_create" template="Amitshree_Marketplace::seller/account/create.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```